# Firefox and other browsers fail to launch after Flash downloaded

Tags: firefox, flash, unity-dash, browser, plugins

Firefox, and now Thunderbird Mail, Chromium, and Browser, fail to launch from Dash after I installed Adobe Flash plugin downloaded from Applications Store.

The problem persisted after removal, replacement, and removal again of the plugin and Firefox. I did not attempt to run the failed applications from the command line since they should have worked when launched from the Unity Desktop menus. Firefox crash exceptions raised and reports sent, no replies from Firefox.

Ubuntu 16.04 Unity Dash.

Comment: How did you install Flash Player? Does the problem persist if you remove it again? What's the program output you run any of those applications in a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T)?

Comment: Downloaded Adobe Flash plugin from Applications Store, problem persisted after removal, replacement, and removal again. Did not attempt to run the failed applications from the command line since they should have worked when launched from the Unity Desktop menus, the reason for the request for assistance. Application launch functionality has been restored after executing dpkg.

Comment: I asked for the terminal output not because it has a higher chance to work but because it may divulge useful information as to the cause of the issue. Also could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**GRUB > Recovery Mode > Repair Broken Packages** solved the problem.

[image: dpkg]

Comment: That's essentially `sudo apt update && sudo apt install -f` except without a reboot to recovery mode.